# Unexpected Output... This output is not what I expected in any way. What is this

Tags: java, exception

I expect the given code to write the following in the text file named OutFile.txt in the src folder (and a copy of this file is present the main directory of the project, where other folders like src and res are present) of this project:

```
Value at: 0 = 0
Value at: 1 = 1
Value at: 2 = 2
```

But it does not write anything in the file. and gives this output in console:

```
0
0

0
0
0
```

CODE:-

```
package exception_handling_1;

//Note: This class won't compile by design!
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListOfNumbers {

 private List<Integer> list;
 private static final int SIZE = 3;

 public ListOfNumbers () {
     list = new ArrayList<Integer>(SIZE);
     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
         list.add(new Integer(i));
     }
 }


 static PrintWriter out;

 public void writeList() {
     //PrintWriter out=null;
     try{
     out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("OutFile.txt"));
     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
         out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + list.get(i));
     }
     }catch (Exception e){
         System.out.println("IO Exception!");
     }finally {
         out.close();
         }
 }


}
```

Please tell me why am I getting this output. Thank you.

Comment: Put in some `System.out.println(...)` at points where you expect certain output and then keep putting these in until you find one that doesn't give the expected output. Then from there figure out why that section of code isn't `correct`.

Comment: Show more of your code, specifically the code that creates a `ListOfNumbers` and calls `writeList()`.

Comment: As written, plus a `static main` to kick it off, works correctly for me. There must be some other code.

Comment: This is only possible if `writeList()` is never called or if the file is erased by something else afterwards. You should show us more.

Comment: How are you running this? What commands, etc.?

Comment: @CyrilleKa I have written just this much and executed. in eclipse. I forgot about main(). I am following [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) tutorial and there is no main() there as well.

Comment: That could be your problem. Eclipse is probably not actually running your code, and instead is doing... something else. I'm not that familiar with Eclipse's compiler/runner. Make a `main` method, create a `ListOfNumbers` in it, and call `writeList()` on that.

Comment: Also note that, if your call to `FileWriter` throws an exception, then it will jump to the `catch` block and `out` will still be `null`; once it reports the exception (and it can be very helpful and informative to print out the exception `e`, rather than just saying "Exception"), it will call `close()` on `out`, giving you a `NullPointerException` in addition to the first exception. It is good practice (as is done in that tutorial) to do a null check on `out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it is working fine exactly what your guessing the output

```
package com.prectice;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ListOfNumbers {

     private List<Integer> list;
     private static final int SIZE = 3;

     public ListOfNumbers () {
         list = new ArrayList<Integer>(SIZE);
         for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
             list.add(new Integer(i));
         }
     }


     static PrintWriter out;

     public void writeList() {
         //PrintWriter out=null;
         try{
         out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("OutFile.txt"));
         for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
             System.out.println("Value at: " + i + " = " + list.get(i));
         }
         }catch (Exception e){
             System.out.println("IO Exception!");
         }finally {
             out.close();
             }
     }
     public static void main (String[] args){
            ListOfNumbers list = new ListOfNumbers();
            list.writeList();
          }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Code works correctly if implemented using a main method.

```
public class testRun{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    ListOfNumbers list = new ListOfNumbers();
    list.writeList();
  }
}
```